# How to execute store procedure multiple time in simplejdbccall spring

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

```
 simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);        
 simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("sp_login")        
    .addDeclaredRowMapper(parameterName, rowMapper)
    .returningResultSet(parameterName, rowMapper);

    simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("userid", Types.VARCHAR));
    simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("username", Types.VARCHAR));
    simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlOutParameter("result", Types.INTEGER));    

  Map<String, Object> result = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
    .addValue("userid", ""+i)
    .addValue("username", "user"+i);

        result=simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);              

    }
```

I want to executing procedure 100 times.
Is this is the right way?
or any alternative executing for a single steps?

Comment: What's your problem with this implementation? Any error are you worried about something specific?